# vba finding something in one worksheet and copying value to same location in another worksheet

Tags: vba

This is driving me insane, I have been at this for 2 weeks now and I am getting nowhere and this is only the first part of quite a complicated( for me) project. I have 1 workbook with 3 sheets (availability)(allocation)(final). I collect peoples availability then I am hoping to perform a series of tasks. column (a) has a list of peoples names ( this is not fixed and could expand and contract) the headings of the other columns are dates ( this is not fixed and could expand and contract). First I need to search through all the columns ( in availability) and find an instance of (x1) record the name of the person and the address of the cell where (x1) was found. This I have done and using ( immediate) I can see that the name and cell location is being found. the next bit is to open the allocation sheet find the persons name and then put (x1) in the same cell address that it was found in. I have added the code to activate the (allocation) worksheets and set the range where I want the search for the name to begin, however when I run the code it gets to line  "Worksheets("allocation").Activate" and gives the error "Application-defined or object-defined error". I have no idea why. You will see from the code that I am a real beginner with VBA as I am sure there is a much more  efficient way of writing this code, however this is what I have come up with after 2 weeks of pains taking searching. If you are able to help with this and or suggest any improvements could I ask that you please comment any code so I know what it is doing otherwise I am never going to be able to work out what is going on and learn anything.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Dim namerange As Range
'Dim namecell As Range
'Dim firstcell As String
'Dim singlecell As Range
Dim listofcellsb As Range
Dim listofcellsc As Range
Dim listofcellsd As Range
Dim listofcellse As Range
Dim listofcellsf As Range
Dim listofcellsg As Range
Dim listofcellsh As Range
Dim listofcellsi As Range
Dim listofcellsj As Range
Dim listofcellsk As Range
Dim listofcellsl As Range
Dim listofcellsm As Range
Dim listofcellsn As Range
Dim listofcellso As Range
Dim listofcellsp As Range
Dim listofcellsq As Range
Dim listofcellsr As Range
Dim listofcellss As Range
Dim listofcellst As Range
Dim listofcellsu As Range
Dim listofcellsv As Range
Dim listofcellsw As Range
Dim listofcellsx As Range
Dim listofcellsy As Range
Dim listofcellsz As Range
Dim addresscell As String
Dim namecell As String




Set listofcellsb = Range("b4", Range("b3").End(xlDown))

Worksheets("allocation").Activate
Range("a3").Select

    For Each singlecellb In listofcellsb
        If singlecellb.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellb.Offset(0, 0).Address
            ActiveCell.Value = singlecellb.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellb
Worksheets("availability").Activate

Set listofcellsc = Range("c4", Range("c3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellc In listofcellsc
        If singlecellc.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellc.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellc.Offset(0, -2).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellc

Set listofcellsd = Range("d4", Range("d3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecelld In listofcellsd
        If singlecelld.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecelld.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecelld.Offset(0, -3).Value
        End If
    Next singlecelld

Set listofcellse = Range("e4", Range("e3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecelle In listofcellse
        If singlecelle.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecelle.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecelle.Offset(0, -4).Value
        End If
    Next singlecelle

Set listofcellsf = Range("f4", Range("f3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellf In listofcellsf
        If singlecellf.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellf.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellf.Offset(0, -5).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellf

Set listofcellsg = Range("g4", Range("g3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellg In listofcellsg
        If singlecellg.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellg.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellg.Offset(0, -6).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellg

Set listofcellsh = Range("h4", Range("h3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellh In listofcellsh
        If singlecellh.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellh.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellh.Offset(0, -7).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellh

Set listofcellsi = Range("i4", Range("i3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecelli In listofcellsi
        If singlecelli.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecelli.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecelli.Offset(0, -8).Value
        End If
    Next singlecelli

Set listofcellsj = Range("j4", Range("j3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellj In listofcellsj
        If singlecellj.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellj.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellj.Offset(0, -9).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellj

Set listofcellsk = Range("k4", Range("k3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellk In listofcellsk
        If singlecellk.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellk.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellk.Offset(0, -10).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellk

Set listofcellsl = Range("l4", Range("l3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecelll In listofcellsl
        If singlecelll.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecelll.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecelll.Offset(0, -11).Value
        End If
    Next singlecelll

Set listofcellsm = Range("m4", Range("m3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellm In listofcellsm
        If singlecellm.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellm.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellm.Offset(0, -12).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellm

Set listofcellsn = Range("n4", Range("n3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecelln In listofcellsn
        If singlecelln.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecelln.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecelln.Offset(0, -13).Value
        End If
    Next singlecelln

Set listofcellso = Range("o4", Range("o3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecello In listofcellso
        If singlecello.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecello.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecello.Offset(0, -14).Value
        End If
    Next singlecello

Set listofcellsp = Range("p4", Range("p3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellp In listofcellsp
        If singlecellp.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellp.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellp.Offset(0, -15).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellp

Set listofcellsq = Range("q4", Range("q3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellq In listofcellsq
        If singlecellq.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellq.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellq.Offset(0, -16).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellq

Set listofcellsr = Range("r4", Range("r3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellr In listofcellsr
        If singlecellr.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellr.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellr.Offset(0, -17).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellr

Set listofcellss = Range("s4", Range("s3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecells In listofcellss
        If singlecells.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecells.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecells.Offset(0, -18).Value
        End If
    Next singlecells

Set listofcellst = Range("t4", Range("t3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellt In listofcellst
        If singlecellt.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellt.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellt.Offset(0, -19).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellt

Set listofcellsu = Range("u4", Range("u3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellu In listofcellsu
        If singlecellu.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellu.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellu.Offset(0, -20).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellu

Set listofcellsv = Range("v4", Range("v3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellv In listofcellsv
        If singlecellv.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellv.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellv.Offset(0, -21).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellv

Set listofcellsw = Range("w4", Range("w3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellw In listofcellsw
        If singlecellw.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellw.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellw.Offset(0, -22).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellw

Set listofcellsx = Range("x4", Range("x3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellx In listofcellsx
        If singlecellx.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellx.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellx.Offset(0, -23).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellx

Set listofcellsy = Range("y4", Range("y3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecelly In listofcellsy
        If singlecelly.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecelly.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecelly.Offset(0, -24).Value
        End If
    Next singlecelly

Set listofcellsz = Range("z4", Range("z3").End(xlDown))
    For Each singlecellz In listofcellsz
        If singlecellz.Value = "x1" Then
            Debug.Print singlecellz.Offset(0, 0).Address
            Debug.Print singlecellz.Offset(0, -25).Value
        End If
    Next singlecellz

'Worksheets("allocation").Activate


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to change it to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("allocation").Activate ?. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly then you might be looking for something like this.

This will loop through columns 2 to 26 in the availability sheet and will copy any X1's into the corresponding column on the allocation sheet (in the row with the same name)

Create a new module by right clicking in the project window of the VBA editor and selecting Insert... Module. Then paste the below code in - You will then need to call this sub in the on click event of the command button.

```
Public Sub copyX1s()
Dim listofcells As Range
Dim currentname As String
Dim foundRow As Integer
Dim foundColumn As Integer
Dim i as integer

For i = 2 To 26

    Sheets("Availability").Activate
    Sheets("Availability").Range("A2").Select
    If Not Sheets("Availability").Cells(2, i) = "" Then
        Sheets("Availability").Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(2, i).End(xlDown)).Select
    Else
        GoTo skip:  'If the column has no data then skip to next column
    End If
    Set listofcells = Selection

    Sheets("Allocation").Activate
    Sheets("Allocation").Range("A2").Select

    For Each singleCell In listofcells
        If singleCell = "X1" Then
            foundColumn = singlecell.Column
            currentName = Sheets("Availability").Range("A" & singleCell.Row)
            Set foundName = Sheets("Allocation").Range("A:A").Find(What:=currentName, LookIn:=xlValues)
            foundRow = foundName.Row
            Sheets("Allocation").Cells(foundRow, foundColumn) = "X1"
        End If
    Next singleCell
skip:
Next i

End Sub
```

The for each loop at the end gets the column number where "X1" was found and the persons name in column A. It then finds the row with that persons name in "Allocation" (in case the names are a different order). It then puts "X1" into the respective cell in the "Allocation" sheet.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write this unfortunately I get an error as soon as it reaches the line "Sheets("availability").Range("a2").Select" application defined or object defined error. it would be nice to know what exactly this is doing as it looks like a way more efficient way of achieving the result I need but as it is not commented there are bits that I just don't understand

Comment: my apologies you have commented but I did not see it when I wrote my reply (did not refresh) and I think the code fails on the sheets.activate line rather than the one below it

Comment: Hmm, I have tested and seems to be working. Silly question but is the sheet "Availability" spelt exactly the same? Maybe try changing to sheets(1) instead of sheets("Availability")

Comment: Hi, @Graham i suspect that you put your code behind a worksheet, can you shift your code inside a module instead

Comment: Ah yes, that will be it. I created a new module for this code. Sorry, should've spotted that. I've updated my answer

Comment: Genius... that works perfectly thank you so much. With any luck I can use some of that code to do the next part of this, once again thank you

Comment: presumably I can call that module from a button click?

Comment: Yes. In the onclick event of the button simply put  - Call copyX1s

Comment: Leroy, I have clicked the "this answer is useful" but it does not seem to change anything and I can't find anything to say "accept this answer" found it doh!

Answer (score 0):

You can try add ThisWorkbook. before Worksheets as KeenLearner mentioned, or you can just use directly object name (i guess it's up to excel language version)

```
Sub test()

List1.Activate
Range("a3").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and get a 424 run-time error object required